# Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ is it has index $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm stuck on this question for hours. I think I need a little help and a different point of view to complete it.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and suppose that $H$ has index two in $G$, i.e., that there are precisely two elements in $G/H$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been answered already in [here][1].


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal

Comment: You will also find two proofs in the statement of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89598/mystified-by-rotmans-proof-of-normality-of-index-2-subgroups).

Answer (score 1):

I have another proof of the folowing :

The number of left cosets of $H$ is equal to the numer of the right cosets.
Now $G = H \cup aH= H \cup Ha$ (H has index 2), hence $aH=Ha$ and H is a normal subgroup.